# Why Does String.Format Discriminate?

Tags: c#, .net

String.Format will happily work correctly with an array of strings, but fails when dealing with an array of ints with exception :

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

```
        string result = null;
        var words = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
        result = String.Format("Count {0}{1}{2}", words); //This works.

        var nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        result = String.Format("Count {0}{1}{2}", nums); //This throws an exception.
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because the `string.Format` overload you are using wants `object[]`. A `string` is a reference type, so `string[]` can be implicitly cast to `object[]`, but `int` is a value type, and would have to be boxed before being put in an array of objects. So when you're using `int` it selects another overload that just takes one parameter, and then passes the entire `int[]` as a single object instead of passing each int by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Because ToString() method is called for Array of ints. And it's becomes 1 object.
This code:

```
var nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
result = String.Format("Count {0}", nums);
```

Will result:
Count System.Int32[]